# Netcat (nc / ncat) cannot be interrupted in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netcat

I have a service that does some tasks and then opens a port so that other services know it's finished. I use `nc` to do that: `nc -l -k -p 1337`. I use `docker-compose` to manage services.

When shutting down the services, the service running `nc` always takes several seconds to close while it should be instant. I think the process doesn't interrupt and docker has to kill it. If I run `nc` on the same service via `docker-compose run` I cannot interrupt the process via Ctrl+C.

When running `nc` locally it can instantly be terminated via Ctrl+C.

How can I create a service running `nc -l -k -p 1337` which can be interrupted?

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache netcat-openbsd

COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...

nc -l -k -p 1337
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  nc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

`docker-compose up --build`

OR:

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...

exec "$@"
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  nc:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: nc -l -k -p 1337
```

`docker-compose up --build`

`docker-compose run --rm nc nc -l -k -p 1337`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `nc` actually responds to signals under normal circumstances, you need to:

1. Use `exec`
2. Use the list version of command.

So in the first case, add an `exec` to the shell script.

And in the second case, probably need `command: ["nc", "-l", "-k", "-p", "1337"]` in the compose file.

See https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/ for full checklist.

Comment: `nc` normally responds. I tried both and it's the same. In the first example `exec nc -l -k -p 1337` and in the second example with `exec "$@"` the list version of the command.

Comment: Also, other services I run react to signals without `exec` or the list version of the command.